# unity.mvc3 and Unit of Work in ntier app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container, unit-of-work

Slowly putting an MVC app together with class libraries: MVC > Services > IRepository > EFRepository. Now at the moment, my EFRepository implementations each create a new dbContext in their constructor but this prevents testing so I need to inject the dbContext instead.

I am successfully using unity.mvc3 for DI throughout the rest of my app but am confused as to how to correctly implement the dbContext injection.

- Does a dbContext act as a Unit of Work?
- Is it correct to inject a dbContext into a Repository?
- Am I right in thinking that a dbContext needs to be instantiated per request?

Think I'm just a bit lost on where to go from here. I was thinking that I should have a Unit of Work but it seems to me this would happen at the service layer.

All help appreciated,

James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Yes (but you could wrap into a custom unit of work)
- Yes
- Yes (Hierarchical lifetime manager in Unity.MVC3)

Comment: Concise, I like it! I have been looking into this more and it seems that the Repo classes should not call context.save, they should just change state. Its in the UoW that state is persisted to the db. Now Repos need the context to change state but who then calls context.save? The Service? Struggling to work out how to set this all up!

Comment: Take a look at my blog engine: http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/2/7/aspnet-mvc-3-razor-based-blog-engine-with-sql-ce-40 Perhaps you can reuse some of the concepts. I'm currently not using Unity.MVC3, but I plan to update soon.